# restrict the number of network connections on a network port

Tags: networking

I am wondering what is the term to describe the below situation in computer network.

I have a network point in my office and it is ONLY limited to 3 DHCP clients. It means if you put a 5 port switch behind the network point, you only can get 3 clients get IP address assigned by DHCP server and only those 3 clients can access the internet.

So what is the technology to restrict the number of connections on this network point?
Is it from Cisco? Because our office is using Cisco switches.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exotic technology at work here. DHCP servers always have a limited range of IP addresses to work with, called the "pool". Apparently, the pool size is set to three. This is configurable on almost every router, not exclusively on Cisco hardware.